# How to get proxy_render_size via python?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I need to get the value of the [Proxy Render Size](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.MovieClipUser.html?highlight=proxy_render_size#bpy.types.MovieClipUser.proxy_render_size) using python, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

When I mouse over, this is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bpy.context.space_data.proxy_render_size
```

The context must be correct for this to work.